# Use of ConfigurationProperties with inner class results in "properties were left unbound" exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated `@Configuration`-class called **LibraryConfig**. It uses an inner class as a type definition for a property/configuration struture. When the class is an inner class instead of a standalone class I get **"Elements [...] were left unbound"** errors/exceptions. Why is this so and how can I fix it?

**application.yml**

```
initdata:
  library:
    name: awesome library
    books:
      - title: Book1
        author: Author Abc
      - title: Book2
        author: Author Xyz
```

**LibraryConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "initdata.library")
public class LibraryConfiguration {
    private String name;
    private List<Book> books;

    // getters left out for simplicity of example
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    public LibraryConfiguration() {
    }

    public static class Book {
        private String title;
        private String author;

        public Book() {
        }
        // getters left out for simplicity of example
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public void setAuthor(String author) {
            this.author = author;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either create a standalone class or you must declare inner classes as `static class`! Otherwise Spring doesn't see it just as a "type definition" but tries to create an instance of it - which of course doesn't work with the given `yml`-configuration. Change the code to the following

```
// ...
public LibraryConfiguration() {
}

// This class MUST be static, otherwise Spring will tell "Elements [...] were left unbound".
// If it's static, it's just a "type definition";
// otherwise spring tries to create an insance
public static class Book {
    private String title;
    private 
// ...
```